# myetherwallet +Advanced: Add Data

Tags: wallets

I want to buy tokens in the Monaco Token sale through MyEtherWallet but not sure what to add in the [+Advanced: Add Data] section of the transaction. Cheers.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/MonacoCard/comments/6cbbm5/how_to_contribute_to_the_monaco_card_token_event/

Comment: Thanks Badr. It says in the add data section - input your personal reference number. What is my personal reference number? Is this a number I just make up myself or do I have to get this personal reference number from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

TO buy Monaco Token, I think you should visit their website https://mona.co/tokensale.html you will find upper right a `Token sell` tab.
click on it and then follow the steps in the end you will get your personal reference number (Data to put in the Data field in myetherwallet).

[image]

Comment: Hey Badr, thanks for your help mate. I found the data and it appeared to work. Cheers.

Comment: Happy to hear that please accept my answer if it answer your question, if it does not, post your own answer explaining how you did it.